# getting error while viewing pdf file in an email from postmark email attachment feature

Tags: node.js, base64, fs, postmark

I don't know which encoding to do while sending email attachment from postmark attachments feature in the Content field.

I have already tried the following method to convert the pdf file to base64 but not find working:

```
fs.readFileSync("./filename.pdf").toString('base64')
////////
pdf2base64("./filename.pdf").then(
        (response) => {
            base= response //cGF0aC90by9maWxlLmpwZw==
        }
    ).catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error); //Exepection error....
        }
    )
/////
 function base64_encode(file) {
    // read binary data
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
    return new Buffer.from(bitmap.toString('utf-8'),'base64');
}
```

The code from which I am trying to send email is below:

```
var client = new postmark.ServerClient("*****");
  client.sendEmail({
    "From": "example@abc.com",
    "To": "abc@abc.com",
    "Subject": "Test",
    "TextBody": "please find attached file of your agreement",
    "Attachments": [
      {
        "Name":  'index.pdf',        
     "Content":fs.readFileSync("./filename.pdf").toString('base64'),
       "ContentType": "application/pdf"
      }
    ]
  }).then((result) => {
    console.log("the result is :", result)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("error is : ", err)
  });
```

All I want it to find the method of how to encode as per the requirement for this email attachment. What should I put in the content field to send the errorless file

Answer (score 1):

Can you reach out to our support team about this? They'll definitely be able to help. https://postmarkapp.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert your file in Base64 string.

For this, you can use the following function.

```
const blobToBase64 = blob => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            resolve(reader.result);
          };
        });
      };
```

After blob/file converting to Base64 string, you have remove the following substring from Base64 string.

> data:application/pdf;base64

You can do it by following code:

```
        const updatedBase64String = res.replace("data:application/pdf;base64,", "")
```

Now you can use the string in your content.

The complete code for you would like as

```
const blobToBase64 = blob => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };
    });
  };
  
   blobToBase64(pdfConvertedToBlob).then(res => {
       const updatedBase64String =  res.replace("data:application/pdf;base64,", "")
          
       client.sendEmail({
          "From": "example@abc.com",
          "To": "abc@abc.com",
          "Subject": "Test",
          "TextBody": "please find attached file of your agreement",
          "Attachments": [
              {
                  "Name":  'index.pdf',        
                  "Content": updatedBase64String,
                  "ContentType": "application/pdf"
              }
           ]
       }).then((result) => {
           console.log("the result is :", result)
       }).catch((err) => {
           console.log("error is : ", err)
       });
    }
```

One thing, to remember. First you have to convert your local PDF file to **BLOB**

For this, you have two choices.
First get the file from API, and get it in **BLOB** format like as

```
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: deployedServer,
    data: data,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    responseType: 'blob',
 })
  .then((pdfConvertedToBlob) => {
      // it is blob data
   });
```

Second you can convert it by input type file, and uploading local file there, and using it. You can use it as below.

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" />

// now js code

if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
 } else {
     alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
 }

 function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    let pdfConvertedToBlob = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object

 }
```

Hope it will helpful to you.